# Integrating Windows Active Directory with latest version of Spinnaker

Tags: active-directory, amazon-eks, spinnaker

Unable to login to the Spinnaker GUI after enabling Windows Active Direcotry authenctication and authorization. Spinnaker GUI keeps on spinning between Hello and Authentication after entering the AD Username/password

We have Spinnaker deployment which is working fine on 1.13.12. We upgraded to latest version of 1.16.2 but since the upgrade our authentication bit is broken. After entering credentials the GUI keeps on spinning between Authentication and Hello messages. There are no obvious error messages or logs on any of the services except the following (similar warning messages for other services as well)

```
Request from: com.netflix.spinnaker.okhttp.MetricsInterceptor.doIntercept(MetricsInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.okhttp.OkHttpMetricsInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpMetricsInterceptor.java:33)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.fiat.config.RetrofitConfig$RetryingInterceptor.intercept(RetrofitConfig.java:118)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.okhttp.MetricsInterceptor.doIntercept(MetricsInterceptor.java:78)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.okhttp.OkHttpMetricsInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpMetricsInterceptor.java:33)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.fiat.providers.internal.Front50Service.lambda$getAllServiceAccounts$2(Front50Service.java:78)
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.fiat.providers.internal.SimpleJava8HystrixCommand.run(SimpleJava8HystrixCommand.java:54)
```

The setup works ok till 1.13.12 release of spinnaker but not any further.

Any one managed to get spinnaker working with Windows AD (LDAP) authentication and authorization?

Comment: Have you tried to enable debug logs for related services?

Comment: i am trying to set up Oauth custom provider and is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using federation with Azure. IT would use the supported OAuth Spinnaker provider for [Azure](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authentication/oauth/azure/).